# Difference in architecture between SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2005, security

I've been asked to identify the architecture differences between Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and 2012. I've been pointed out to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545450.aspx but I haven't seen anything talking about the architecture.

So what are the differences? I'm specially interested on security-related differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of them, a lot of articles on the topic if you have google at it.

Some of them:

- Default Schema for Windows Groups

  - User Defined Server Roles
  - Enhancments to Auditing
  - User Contained Databases, authentication without logins.
  - TDE - Transparent Data Encryption
  - Hashing Functions - improved.